# How to hide "Log in or register to post comments" when I've already disabled displaying comments?

Tags: comments

I already disabled comments. How can I remove the "Log in or register to post comments" text at the bottom of articles or other content types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to disable the "links" section or you'll see this message.

Go to the `Administration > Structure > Content types > Article` page. Drag comments and links to the disabled section. Repeat for any other content types where you want to hide this message.

[image: Screenshot]